# Sonar: Validar alterações a partir de determinada data

Tags: c#, testes, team-foundation-server, sonarqube

Utilizo o Git integrado ao Team Foundation Server. A ideia é colocar o Sonar como um step no TFS para interromper o build conforme a regra estabelecida.
Preciso saber se é possível o Sonar aplicar os testes apenas para alterações feitas à partir de determinada data. Exemplo: tenho o histórico de 1 ano de alterações no sistema. Vou colocar o step do Sonar hoje. Quero que ele verifique apenas as alterações realizadas a partir de hoje.
Para diminuir o impacto inicial, a ideia seria fazer um marco de validação, e depois validar o que ficou pra trás. É possível?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O Sonar vai rodar em cima do build, não em todo o seu histórico de código, porém, é preciso de uma base histórica para análisar se o código está melhorando ou não.
O Sonar avalia tendência, por isso a análise se dá em cima do histórico.

Mas sim, é possível pontuar a partir de quando o SonarQube irá fazer a análise, setando um ponto no passado para isso.

Comment: Bom, eu como eu seto este ponto?

Answer (score 1):

No seu build é necessário adicionar 3 passos:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**1) Prepare Analysis**

Configura qual o projeto do SonarQube irá subir as informações. Neste passo temos que Configurar o Endpoint, Project key, project Name e Project Version

**2) Run Code Analysis**

Este passo deve ser adicionado logo após o build

**3) Publish Quality Gate Result**

Deve ser adicionado para publicar o resultado

Após isto, cada build que rodar será publicado o resultado:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Para maiores informações, segue o link da documentação oficial:

https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SCAN/Analyzing+with+SonarQube+Extension+for+VSTS-TFS